# GridToolbarExport from Material UI stop to work after last version? 5.0.0-alpha.37

Tags: reactjs, typescript, datagrid, material-ui

I'm create a custom toolbar for my Data Grid with the following structure :

```
  return (
    <GridToolbarContainer>
      <GridToolbarColumnsButton />
      <GridToolbarFilterButton />
      <GridToolbarDensitySelector />
      <GridToolbarExport />
    </GridToolbarContainer>
  );
```

All the components work normally but the GridToolbarExport is now telling this :

[error from typescript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IK1Y4.png)

i updated my version to this one :

"@material-ui/core": "^5.0.0-alpha.37",
"@material-ui/data-grid": "^4.0.0-alpha.32",

am i missing something ?
thanks!

Comment: This seems to be a bug in material ui. Did you file a bug report?

Answer (score 1):

I upgraded to Material-UI v5 and ran into this issue as well. I managed to get it working by passing in "props: any". I'm still not sure the correct type Module Augmentation to get this going for Typescript. Additional help would be great.

```
function CustomToolbar(props: any) {
  return (
    <GridToolbarContainer>
      <GridToolbarColumnsButton />
      <GridToolbarFilterButton {...props} />
      <GridToolbarDensitySelector />
      <GridToolbarExport {...props} />
    </GridToolbarContainer>
  );
}
```

Comment: I now use the following, based on your answer `<GridToolbarFilterButton {...({} as any)} />`. I'm hoping this will be fixed before v5's final release. Did you file a bug report?

Comment: I found some time to create a CodeSandbox and reported the issue. [Material UI Issues](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/27824). You can find the sample code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-v5-datagrid-toolbar-typescript-error-q2ogk?file=/src/data-grid.tsx).

Comment: Thanks  I hadn't had time yet to create an issue so I'm glad you did :)